# RegEx replace with condition: separate adjacent numbers only

Tags: php, regex

I have a txt file with numbers:

```
1-2 c., 3-6 c., 7-8 c., 12-15 c. etc.
```

I need to separate adjacent numbers (1-2 and 7-8 in the example) with " and " while the rest of the numbers I want to leave as they are, so that I get this:

```
1 and 2 c., 3-6 c., 7 and 8 c., 12-15 c. etc.
```

If I wanted to replace all of the hyphens I could do that like this:

```
$newtxt = preg_replace('#(\d+)-(\d+)#', '$1 and $2', $txt);
```

I can do it easily with other means of PHP, but the problem is that I need to do that with the help of regular expressions only. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you "need to"? Is this homework? And no, not possible.

Comment: `preg_replace_callback('#(\d+)-(\d+)#', function($m) {return (abs(($m[1] - $m[2])) == 1) ? "{$m[1]} and {$m[2]}" : $m[0];}, '1-2 c., 3-6 c., 7-8 c., 12-15 c. etc.');` gives you what you want. It doesn't use regex *only*, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @nulluserexception +1, Fantastic! Any way I think that it is needed escape the dash: `'#(\d+)\-(\d+)#'`

Comment: @mario, Actually, I'd "like to" do it using Notepad++. And no, it's not a homework. I do some text editing from time to time and that task appears regularly. If that's not possible, I'll write a php script to cope with that task. Something like the one proposed by @ NullUserException (thanks!).

Comment: @NomikOS No, the dash is only a metacharacter inside character classes. And even then you can get away with not escaping it if you place it in the right spots (eg: `[-abc]`)

Comment: @nulluserexception Got it, thanks. So answer the question and takes your points! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `preg_replace_callback` which will allow you to write a function that returns the required replacement string depending on the matched and captured strings.

```
$str = '1-2 c., 3-6 c., 7-8 c., 12-15 c. etc. ';

$str = preg_replace_callback(
  '/(\d+)-(\d+)/',
  function($match) {
    return $match[2] == $match[1] + 1 ? "$match[1] and $match[2]" : $match[0];
  },
  $str
);

echo $str;
```

**output**

```
1 and 2 c., 3-6 c., 7 and 8 c., 12-15 c. etc.
```

Comment: Hmm looks like you've got the same answer several times. Take your pick!

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_replace_callback and use the function. It is not fully regexp but close to it.

```
function myCallback ($match){
   if($match[1] == $match[2]-1){
       return $match[1]." and ".$match[2];
   } else {
       return $match[0];
   }
}
preg_replace_callback(
    '#(\d+)-(\d+)#',"myCallback",$txt
);
```

Hope it helps.